# How to fine-tune the mt0 model using the Transformers Seq2SeqTrainer?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, fine-tuning

I want to finetune the mt0 model to adapt it for a downstream work.
And following this tutorial (https://medium.com/@tskumar1320/how-to-fine-tune-pre-trained-language-translation-model-3e8a6aace9f), I wrote a piece of code for fine-tuning.
It runs without any errors, but after several epochs of training, I got the eval loss as "nan"(the text generated by model is also '')

the main training code is as follows:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/mt0-large",torch_dtype=torch.float16,device_map="auto")
trainer_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./tmp",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    predict_with_generate=True,
    save_total_limit=1,
    auto_find_batch_size=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
)
data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=model)
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(model=model,args=trainer_args, train_dataset=train_dataset,eval_dataset=eval_dataset,data_collator=data_collator)
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model()
```

and the format of train_dataset and test_dataset is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozy6a.png)

the eval result after 1 epoch:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZowN.png)

and the inference coda is as follows:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("./tmp")
model.to("cuda")
model.eval()

while True:
    s = input("users:")
    autoTokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bigscience/mt0-large")
    inputs = autoTokenizer(s, return_tensors="pt")
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs["input_ids"].to("cuda"), max_new_tokens=256)
        print(outputs)
        result = autoTokenizer.batch_decode(outputs.detach().cpu().numpy(), skip_special_tokens=True)
    print("robot:")
    print(result)
```

the output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK8Cp.png)

I printed out the input parameters just like in the preceding text, and the results appear to be identical to what the tutorial provided.

Because I'm relatively newbie in this field and don't have many alternative solutions at the moment.

Comment: I solve this problem by removing torch_dtype=torch.float16 from AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained. This problem might caused by some precision alignment problem